# Function not loading inside componentDidMount ()

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have the following code:

```
componentDidMount () {
    fetch('/data')
        .then(res => res.json())
        .then(data => this.setState({data}));

    this.countVar();
}

countVar () {
    //iterate through this.state.data and filter out certain values
}
```

The `countVar()` function isn't loading inside `componentDidMount()`. When I did `console.log(this.state.data)` right after the `componentDidMount()`-function, it returned an empty array, so I guess that's the reason.
I tried to use `componentDidUpdate()` instead if `countVar()`, but I didn't consider that that would create an infinite loop. I don't quite know how to handle this.

The data that I'm fetching consists of several object arrays. in `countVar()` I'm filtering out a certain object array, hence the structure of my functions.

Does anyone know how I could solve this problem?

Comment: You can try using the setState callback like so: `.then(data => this.setState({data}, () => this.countVar()));`

Comment: `console.log(this.state.data)` is most likely executing before the state is set as I assume you didn't include it in your `then(...)`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
fetch('/data')
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then(data => this.setState({data}));
```

This code is async. This means that *when* the fetch is complete, it will run the functions passed into the `then` callback. You're running your iteration function directly after registering the promise; not after the promise is resolved.

**ALSO**

`this.setState` is not synchronous. You can't guarantee that after you *request* that the state is set, it is set. It is set some time afterward, but React provides an option for this; you pass in a callback function once state setting is complete.

```
this.setState({ data }, () => console.log('do something'))
```

Comment: yeah actually now that I did that it works perfectly, thank you very much I'll remember that so I don't make mistakes like that again

Answer (score 1):

You should call **this.countVar** inside the **then** of the Promise otherwise it will run before the fetch Promise is over.

Like this:

```
componentDidMount () {
    fetch('/data')
        .then(res => res.json())
        .then(data => {
          this.setState({data}, this.countVar);
        });
}
```

I'm running this.countVar as a callback to setState so that it runs once setState is done.